# cvCvtColor faild

Tags: opencv

I try to run the following program according to what is written on this site
http://www.lirtex.com/robotics/fast-object-tracking-robot-computer-vision/

Initialization parameters

```
CvCapture *capture = cvCaptureFromCAM(0);

int width = ( int )cvGetCaptureProperty( capture, CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH );
int height = ( int )cvGetCaptureProperty( capture, CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT );

IplImage *frame;

 CvSize size = cvSize(640,480);
cvNamedWindow( "Camera", CV_WINDOW_NORMAL  );
cvNamedWindow( "HSV", CV_WINDOW_NORMAL  );
cvNamedWindow( "EdgeDetection", CV_WINDOW_NORMAL  );

cvResizeWindow("Camera",640,480);
cvResizeWindow("HSV",640,480);
cvResizeWindow("EdgeDetection",640,480);



IplImage *  hsv_frame    = cvCreateImage(size, IPL_DEPTH_8U, 3);
IplImage*  thresholded   = cvCreateImage(size, IPL_DEPTH_8U, 1);
```

when im calling the function cvCvtColor like this:

```
cvCvtColor(frame, frame  , CV_BGR2HSV);
```

with the 2nd paramter is equal to the first its work

but when im calling the function like this

```
cvCvtColor(frame, hsv_frame  , CV_BGR2HSV);
```

its fail and throws an exception

Does anyone have any idea why this happens?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Array *frame* is the size of the captured image whereas, *hsv_frame* has been hardcoded to 640x480. The colorspace conversion operation(cvCvtColor) requires that both the source and destination be of the same size and so the exception.

Solution:

a. Use the same size as the input by setting

`CvSize size = cvSize(frame->width, frame->height);`

-OR-

b. If you want the final o/p to be 640x480, resize the input to the required size using: `cvResize`

One final note: The C++ interface is much more intuitive, much more stable and has added features as compared to the C interface. I recommend moving to the C++ interface of OpenCV